# Maria database temp files using up all server space

Tags: database

Our server is crashing on a regular basis, as much as once every few days. The problem is MariaDB is generating multiple large temp files, *.MAD and *.MAI files. This is happening even though we have about a spare 40GB on the server.

We are running CiviCRM 5.63.4 with Drupal 9.5.10, and the CiviCRM database is just over 1GB.

I have tried regularly optimising all the tables, deleting older rows from the larger log tables. I have updated the `innodb_file_per_table` setting to on. But none of this has solved the issue.

A while ago I was having several errors saying the row size was too large so I increased the `innodb_page_size` to 64K. I have a feeling this may be causing the problem? The row size issue may have been happening because we have over 1000 custom fields. Many of our custom field groups are using the maximum amount of indexed custom fields in them.